# Rewrite longdomain URL to short domain URL in wordpress PHP

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have 2 domains, for example

```
longdomain.com
ld.cc
```

Wordpress is running on longdomain.com and user generated content is there which gives unique URL in longdomain automatically by wordpress.

Like

```
longdomain.com/this-is-unique-id/
```

Is it possible to load the long domain url content in shortdomain using the url slug by any means ?

```
longdomain.com/this-is-unique-id/ 
ld.cc/this-is-unique-id/
```

Both URL should give same output, Not redirection, just load the content of longdomain content using short domain, provided i own both domains & can do any URL rewriting server configuration, db access in both domains.

The goal is to build a custom URL shortener with wordpress by aquiring short domain, rather than relying on third party URL shortening services.

Answer (score 4):

Use a redirect via your hosting account.

You would need to configure your DNS records.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to wp-config.php, which will prevent WordPress from redirecting to the long domain.

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a solution :

1 - Create a website for ld.cc on your webserver and point the **DocumentRoot** to longdomain.com's website DocumentRoot.

2 - Install a plugin like this one : 
[Multiple Domains](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain/#description)